# how to write syntax Two-dimensional array two type array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I try array Two-Dimension this

```
  [Int][indexpath.row]
```

How to write ?? I can’t use  `[int[index.path]]`

Error is waring this

```
"Type 'Int.Type' has no subscript members"
```

Comment: `IndexPath`'s `row` is just an `Int`.  You're looking for `[[Int]]`.

Comment: ok I will try again

Comment: @Jaydeep please don’t edit closed questions.  That puts them in the reopen queue and this question does not need to be reopened, it needs to remain closed.